# Can't get all comments from Youtube Data API V3 [Python]

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a python function, which allows you to get all comments from a youtube video. Therefore I use the youtube API v3 comments.list method.

```
key = 'My Key'
textFormat = 'plainText'
part = 'snippet'
maxResult = '100'
order = 'relevance'
nextToken = ''
videoId = 'Ix9NXVIbm2A'

while(True):
        response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?&key="+key+"&part="+part+"&videoId="+idVideo +"&maxResults="+maxResult+"&order="+order+"&pageToken="+nextToken)

        data  = response.json() #kind - etag - ?nextPageToken

        if 'error' in data:
            print(data)
            break

        for item in data['items']:
            snippet = item["snippet"]
            toplevelcomment = snippet['topLevelComment']
            content = toplevelcomment['snippet']

            commentid = toplevelcomment['id']
            authorname = content['authorDisplayName']
            textOriginal = content['textOriginal']

                #lists
            commentids.append(commentid)
            authornames.append(authorname)
            textOriginals.append(textOriginal)


        if 'nextPageToken' in data:
            nextToken = data['nextPageToken']

        else:
            break
```

all progress good from pageToken to another. But when it reaches the pageToken number 13, the API always returns

```
{
'error': 
 {
 'errors': 
  [
   {
    'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 
    'reason': 'processingFailure', 
    'message': 'The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.', 
    'locationType': 'other', 
    'location': 'body'
   }
  ], 
 'code': 400, 
 'message': 'The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.'
 }
}
```

I'm using a valid key and the pageToken is valid too (returned by the API)

Does anyone have the same problems or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your [error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#errors) indicates that you are using an input request that is invalid. You can get an idea in the [code snippet](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#examples) provided by the documentation if possible. `It calls the` **commentThreads.list** `method with the` **videoId** `parameter set to retrieve comments for a video`.

Answer (score 0):

This error come because your api limits is exhausted. Youtube change the limit of api time to time.

And sometimes network problem is also occur. You have to write code for multiple attempt when once request is fail.

You can read full documentation here - [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota][1]

Recently youtube decreased the quota numbers from 1M to 10K per day as of 11-January-2019

currently version 3 allow only 10k units per day.